# Статические свойства

Tags: php, ооп

Отметил для себя необычное поведение статических свойств в экземплярах класса
есть код:

```
    class A{
        public static $key=0;
        public function getKey(){
            return self::$key;
        }
    }
    class B extends A {}
    A::$key = 1;
    $b = new B();
    echo $b->getKey();
```

Здесь все понятно мы изменили статическое свойство класса A::$key = 1; со стороны клиента. И после этого любой экземпляр класса А или наследник этого класса (в данном случае В) будет иметь измененное значение статического свойства $key

Но следующий код мне стал непонятным - в нижеприведенном коде мы изменили статическое свойство экземпляра класса, что автоматически затронуло статическое свойство класса. Это что ? - некая глобальная переменная в рамках всех наследников этого класса? Вот код

```
<?php 

    class A{
        protected static $key=0;
        public function plus(){
            ++self::$key;
        }
        public function getKey(){
            return self::$key;
        }
    }
    class B extends A {}
    $a = new A();
    echo $a->getKey().'</br>';
    $a->plus();
    echo $a->getKey().'</br>';
    $b = new B();
    echo $b->getKey().'</br>';
```

выдал

```
0
1
1
```

Вот еще код

```
<?php 

    class A{
        protected static $key=0;
        public function plus(){
            ++self::$key;
        }
        public function getKey(){
            return self::$key;
        }
    }
    class B extends A {}
    $a = new A();
    echo $a->getKey().'</br>';
    $b = new B();
    $a->plus();
    echo $a->getKey().'</br>';
    echo $b->getKey().'</br>';
```

выдал

```
0
1
1
```

в итоге любое изменение статического свойства в любом наследнике меняет автоматически статическое свойство во ВСЕХ экземплярах - наследниках. Это ж альтернатива глобальным переменным или я чего то не понимаю и почему то об этом в учебниках не пишут.

на основе слов @perfect

поставил эксперимент

```
<?php 

    class A{
        protected static $key=0;
        public function plus(){
            ++self::$key;
        }
        public function getKey(){
            return self::$key;
        }
    }
    class B extends A {}
    class C extends A {}
    $b = new B();
    $c = new C();
    $b->plus();
    echo $c->getKey().'</br>';
```

выдал

```
1
```

в итоге у них глобальная видимость - где бы экземпляры классов не находились

Но это еще не все, как показа практика @chernomyrdin обращаясь к одной и той же статической переменной - можно обращаться к различным участкам оперативной памяти. В итоге "в одной и той же переменной" могут храниться разные значения

```
<?php 

    class A {
        protected static $key=0;
        public function getGlobalKey(){
            return self::$key;
        }
        //применяем позднее статическое связывание
        public function getCurrentKey(){
            return static::$key;
        }
        public function plusGlobalKey(){
            ++self::$key;
        }
        //применяем позднее статическое связывание
        public function plusCurrentKey(){
            ++static::$key;
        }
    }
    class B extends A{
        protected static $key=0;
    }
    class C extends B{}
    $a = new A();
    $a->plusGlobalKey();
    $b = new B();
    echo $a->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $b->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $b->getGlobalKey().'<br/>';
    $a->plusGlobalKey();
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo $a->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $b->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $b->getGlobalKey().'<br/>';
    $b->plusCurrentKey();
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo $a->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $b->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $b->getGlobalKey().'<br/>';
    echo '<hr/>';
    $c = new C();
    echo $c->getCurrentKey().'<br/>';
    echo $c->getGlobalKey().'<br/>';
```

выводит

```
1
0
1
-----------------
2
0
2
-----------------
2
1
2
-----------------
1
2
```

Резюме: @perfect - объяснил почему так происходит

@chernomyrdin - подтолкнул к теме позднего статического связывания - в последнем примере я как раз понял как оно работает

Comment: Почерпнул это из шаблона Interpreter

Comment: `статическое свойство экземпляра класса` - таких нет. вы меняете именно статическое свойство класса.

Comment: А что @vp_arth скажите по поводу последнего примера? чем там является self::$key и чем static::$key; в объекте класса С - получается self::$key принадлежит классу А, а static::$key; принадлежит классу В ?

Comment: Вы безнадёжно испортили вопрос. Вопрос должен быть предельно ясен. По поводу static:: читайте [позднее статическое связывание](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Важно понять, что статические свойства `общие` для всех экземпляров класса и существуют в `единичном` виде (такие поля хранит сам класс). Каждое изменение каким либо экземпляром класса статического свойства отражается на всех остальных экземплярах.

В вашем случае вы один раз выполнили функцию $a->plus(); и с нуля у вас получилась единица в обоих экземплярах.

Что бы вы достаточно смогли разобраться я нарисовал картинку объясняющую принцип хранения статистических переменных внутри памяти.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Область видимости статических переменных ограничена самим классом для защиты от внешнего изменения (в отличие от глобальных переменных) и используется для использования потомками только этого класса (например для обмена какой либо информацией)

Comment: это как раз в учебниках я и видел. Я представлял что класс это печать(оттиск). А экземпляры - уже что то напечатанное. Но для меня было удивлением то что в экземпляре класса ++self::$key; затрагивает свойство не только экземпляра класса, а статическое свойство всех УЖЕ созданных экземпляров классов. Я всегда полагал что ++self::$key; влияет только на статическое свойство экземпляра класса, а выражение A::$key на статическое свойство класса и последующих экземпляров этого класса

Comment: @Mcile как представлять класс это индивидуальная философия. `Но для меня было удивлением то что в экземпляре класса ++self::$key; затрагивает свойство не только экземпляра класса, а статическое свойство всех УЖЕ созданных экземпляров` - потому что это поле общее как я и написал ) представьте что в вашем отпечатаном листе дырка и чтобы посмотреть что должно быть в этой дырке нужно наложить его на оттиск

Answer (score 1):

Со статиками в PHP все сложно, начиная с того как к ним обращатся `self::$key` и `static::$key` причем поведение различное в 5.x и 7.0

Потом вот пример для размышления:

```
class A {
    public function inc () {
        static $value = 0;
        return get_called_class() . '::' . ++$value;
    }
}
class B extends A {}

$a = new A;
echo $a->inc(), "\n";
$b = new B;
echo $b->inc(), "\n";
echo $a->inc(), "\n";
echo $b->inc(), "\n";
$c = new A;
echo $c->inc(), "\n";
echo $c->inc(), "\n";
echo $a->inc(), "\n";
```

Результат работы:

```
A::1
B::1
A::2
B::2
A::3
A::4
A::5
```

Comment: как это ваше "_все сложно_" овтечает на заданный вопрос? И как этот пример относится к вопросу? Речь шла про статические члены класса, тут же статические локальные переменные метода класса.

Comment: Спасибо за доп информацию, ответом будет [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/259627/) Соглашусь с @teran .

Comment: @Mcile приведенная вами статья несколько пугает порой своими утверждениями. Как будто написана для тех кто вообще не ориентируется в ООП вообще, а уже собирается на "_собеседование_". Концептуалельные вещи ООП на любоя языке почему-то называются "подводными камнями". Для изучения языка программирования всегда читайте официальную документацию или спецификацию языка.